# NodeJs how to parse post body sent from Postman

Tags: node.js, postman, http-post

I'm having this simple NodeJs code to handle post request sent from any other origin like Postman

```
const http = require("http");
const { parse } = require("querystring");
const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
console.dir(request.param);

if (request.method === "POST") {
  let body = "";
  request.on("data", (chunk) => {
    body += chunk.toString(); // convert Buffer to string
  });
  request.on("end", () => {
    const result = parse(body);
    console.log(result);
    response.end("ok");
  });
 }
});

const port = 8080;
const host = "127.0.0.1";
server.listen(port, host);
```

When I send post request from Postman with form data like `user:foo` I get it like this in the terminal

```
[Object: null prototype] {
'----------------------------908153651530187984286555\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name': '"user"\r\n\r\nfoo\r\n----------------------------908153651530187984286555--\r\n'
```

And when I run

```
console.log(result.user)
```

I get `undefined`

I changed the parsing body `const result = parse(body);` into this

```
const result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body))
```

And I got

```
----------------------------939697314758807513697606  
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user"

foo
----------------------------939697314758807513697606--
```

but still can't get `result.user`

How can I handle such data by converting it into an object and get the user like this `result.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data in your body is a JSON object, you can just remove the toString in chunks and replace the parse with JSON.parse, like so:

```js
  let body = "";
  request.on("data", (chunk) => {
    body += chunk; // convert Buffer to string
  });
  request.on("end", () => {
    const result = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(result);
    response.end("ok");
  });
```

This will work OK if you sent the data from postman choosing "raw" and "JSON", sending an object as the following in the body:

```json
{
    "user": "john"
}
```

Your current approach, using querystring's parse method, should work well if the data was sent as "x-www-form-urlencoded".

In short, the solution would be to modify the Content-Type header of the request you are sending to your server.